# setting up django with nginx and apache

Tags: django, apache, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, web-deployment

I just started developing in Django a  few days back. After finishing a few applications I read that Django is best served using nginx for static content and a reverse proxy to apache for dynamic contents. Is there a particular reason that this configuration preferred over any other?

Also, although this seems to be the standard approach I havent yet been able to find a proper tutorial or document that walks through such a configuration. Most seem to be incomplete/non-working.

It would be great if someone could explain to me how this is to be done or point in the right direction or maybe link a tutorial here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use nginx and gunicorn/uwsgi configuration, it more common this days and easier to setup/configure that apache. A proper tutorials can be found here:

1) [django + gunicorn](http://honza.ca/2011/05/deploying-django-with-nginx-and-gunicorn) and a more complete tutorial with supervisor, fabric [here](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2011/06/django-gunicorn-nginx-supervisord-fabric-centos55/)

2) [django + uwsgi](http://liangsun.org/posts/django-plus-uwsgi-plus-nginx/)

Comment: I tried the first link but it only shows the nginx welcome page. Also others seem non-ubuntu, will give it a shot anyway.

Comment: If it give you a welcome page that you didnt set a proxy-pass directive.  location / {       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;   }  if its set all request will be passed to gunicorn.

Comment: For ubuntu you can use this app that will do this configuration automatically https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fagungis

Comment: fagungis seems great but at the end of deployment it gives me an error statis project NOT STARTED(apparently supervisor is not able to start gunicorn) and my domain gives a bad gateway error. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Supervisor having issues spwaning the blog project. 
`INFO spawned: 'blog' with pid 15772
INFO exited: blog (exit status 3; not expected)
INFO gave up: blog entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly`

Comment: i reset my server and now it gives me `Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!` anyway thanks for the fagungis solution.